# Counting points/coordinates that lie within a bounding box

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have 2 tables. The first table contains following columns: Start_latitude, start_longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude, sum. The sum column  is empty and needs to be filled based on second table.

The second table contains 3 columns: point_latitude, point_longitude

**Table 1**

```
-------------------------
|45 | 50 | 46 | 51 | null|
----|---------------------
|45 | 54 | 46 | 57 | null|
--------------------------
```

**Table2:**

```
---------------
| 45.5 | 55.2 |
---------------
| 45.8 | 50.6 |
---------------
| 45.2 | 56   |
---------------
```

The null values in table1-row1 would be 1 while in row2 it would be 2. It is the count of number of points that lie within the bounding box.

I can do it in python by writing functions to read values between dataframes. How can this be done in Postgresql. This is a sample problem statement that I came up with for my situation.

Comment: Don't you have any ID columns in your tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
This version was tested on PostgreSql 9.3 using SQL Fiddle

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET sum = sub.point_count
FROM (SELECT a.start_lat, a.end_lat, a.start_lon, a.end_lon, COUNT(*) as point_count
      FROM table1 a, table2 b
      WHERE b.point_lat BETWEEN start_lat AND a.end_lat
        AND b.point_lon BETWEEN a.start_lon AND a.end_lon
      GROUP BY a.start_lat, a.end_lat, a.start_lon, a.end_lon) as sub
WHERE a.start_lat = sub.start_lat
  AND a.end_lat = sub.end_lat
  AND a.start_lon = sub.start_lon
  AND a.end_lon = sub.end_lon;
```

---

*Original answer*

Here is my solution, it is tested on MySQL but there is nothing specific about this code so it should work on PostgreSql as well

```
UPDATE table1 a,
  (SELECT a.start_lat, a.end_lat, a.start_lon, a.end_lon, COUNT(*) as count
   FROM table1 a, table2 b
   WHERE b.point_lat BETWEEN start_lat AND a.end_lat
   AND b.point_lon BETWEEN a.start_lon AND a.end_lon
   GROUP BY a.start_lat, a.end_lat, a.start_lon, a.end_lon) as sub
SET sum = count
WHERE a.start_lat = sub.start_lat
  AND a.end_lat = sub.end_lat
  AND a.start_lon = sub.start_lon
  AND a.end_lon = sub.end_lon
```

Note that this query would be much shorter if table1 contained a PK Id column.